# CSS Background Images Not Showing in Heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have read tons of posts on SO and other help websites on this issue, but so far nothing has helped.  I have images in my CSS that are showing up on my `localhost` but not when I push my app to Heroku.

Here's an example of an image:

```
.hero-000 {
    width: 102%;
    background: url(hero-000.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

As suggested by other posts, I have added this to my `application.rb`:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

I also added this to my `production.rb`:

```
  config.serve_static_files = true
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.digest = true
```

And I followed the steps on the Heroku website to precompile assets [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline).

I really don't know where to go from here, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: specify image-path like this in css : background-image: image-url("hero-000.jpg")

Comment: where is you `hero-000.jpg` file is located?

Comment: @PardeepSaini Doing it this way makes the image disappear even on my `localhost`.  And @uzaif the images are in `app/assets/images/` but since I tried to precompile them there seems to be a copy in `public/assets/` as well...

Comment: you need to change the extension of your css file from `.css` to `.css.scss`

Comment: I changed the extension but the images still don't appear.

Comment: did you installed `sass-rails` gem .

Comment: Yes, sass-rails is installed.

Comment: try this background-image: `url(image-path('hero-000.jpg'));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112464/discussion-between-pardeep-saini-and-liz).

Comment: Did you clean the assets and then did production as ur env while doing rake assets:precompile?

Comment: Unfortunately, using `url(image-path('hero-000.jpg'));` as a background image yields a sass syntax error.

Comment: @uDaY, I also tried cleaning the assets before doing `rake assets:precompile` and then pushing it to Heroku, but the images still don't display.

Comment: Can you post the error trace?

Comment: There is no error, it's simply showing the webpage without the background images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved using a helper. Try this on your css:

```
background-image: image-url("hero-000.jpg");
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried that but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Try to add the gem: 'rails_12factor', group: :production

Comment: This is to serve static assets

Comment: I do have that gem in my production group.

Comment: Did you run heroku run bash on your terminal?

Comment: No.  I'm new to Heroku.  What do I do once I'm inside the new dyno?